# JPQL query : Finding the largest object in a collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have two entities

```
Class A{

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<B> b;

private Integer credits;
//other fields
}

Class B{

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "a_fk")
private A a;

private Integer reputations;
//other fields
}
```

**Now I want select the B with the highest reputation for each A.**

What I am doing currently is

```
 "select a FROM A a ORDER BY a.credits DESC"; //maximum results set to 500
```

And then finding the highest B in each A.

```
 for (A a: aList) {
            bList.add(Collections.max(a.getB(),new bComparator()));
        }
```

But this solution isn't very intuitive.

I tried writing the query below, but doesn't give the desired result.

```
select b FROM B b WHERE b.reputations = (SELECT MAX(b.reputations) FROM B bInner WHERE bInner.a.id = b.a.id) ORDER BY b.a.credits DESC
```

Any suggestions for an optimized query?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your query, I've tested it:

```
select distinct a,b
FROM A a JOIN a.b b  
WHERE b.reputations=(SELECT MAX(b2.reputations) FROM B b2 WHERE b2.a=a)
```

Comment: That doesn't work, I get all the Bs of an A, which is not desired. I want only the B with highest reputations.

Comment: I've just tried it and runs perfectly, the generated query is: `SELECT DISTINCT t0.ID, t0.CREDITS, t1.ID, t1.REPUTATIONS, t1.A_ID FROM A t0, B t1 WHERE ((t1.REPUTATIONS = (SELECT MAX(t2.REPUTATIONS) FROM B t2 WHERE (t2.A_ID = t0.ID))) AND (t1.A_ID = t0.ID))`. I've inserted a1 and a2, with credits 1 and 2 respectively, and b1,b2,b3,b4,b5, with reputations 1,2,3,4,5 and connected b1,b2,b3 to a1 and b4,b5 to a2. Running the query I get a1,b3 and a2,b5

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I had a personal emergency, will let you know in a day.